# What are these warnings in the pre-launch report in google play?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I made the report prior to the launch in google play and I shot 12 warnings. My game was made in unit 2017.1.1 and I have Android SDK 28. I want to correct these problems that cause these ads. google throws me the following "Google can not guarantee that the following APIs will work on the current versions of Android because they are on the gray list. Some may already be restricted for their destination SDK."

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at akj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):78)
    at akj.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):76)
    at akj.<clinit>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):116)
    at akj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):26)
    at ajd.<clinit>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):2502)
    at ajd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):20)
    at aio.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):26)
    at ajl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):3)
    at ajl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):8)
    at ahr.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):88)
    at ww.h_(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):23)
    at tl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):18)
    at td.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):12)
    at tg.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):56)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at xs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):5)
    at xs.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):4)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)


----------


StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at aMq.a(PG:4)
    at aMK.a(PG:10)
    at aMr.a(PG:50)
    at cvB.<init>(PG:4)
    at cuV.run(PG:9)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)


----------


StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/media/AudioSystem;->getPrimaryOutputFrameCount()I
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:151)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source:20)
[ 06-12 00:26:52.212 15139:15203 D/         ]
PlayerBase::PlayerBase()
[ 06-12 00:26:52.212 15139:15203 D/         ]
TrackPlayerBase::TrackPlayerBase()


----------


StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/media/AudioSystem;->getPrimaryOutputSamplingRate()I
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:151)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source:20)


----------


StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at cyw.a(PG:9)
    at cyE.a(PG:12)
    at org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SmartSelectionClient.<init>(PG:5)
    at czl.a(Unknown Source:7)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.e(PG:243)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.d(PG:210)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(PG:81)
    at vE.run(PG:15)
    at aKc.a(PG:13)
    at aKd.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at org.chromium.base.task.PostTask.b(PG:13)
    at aKc.a(PG:7)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.b(PG:6)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(PG:107)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:422)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:348)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:331)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:318)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:308)
    at a.a.a.a.a.e.a.b(SourceFile:1)
    at a.a.a.a.a.e.a.a(SourceFile:1)
    at a.a.a.a.a.h.c.b(SourceFile:3)
    at a.a.a.a.a.h.c.a(SourceFile:5)
    at a.a.a.a.a.h.j.a(SourceFile:12)
    at com.tappx.sdk.android.TappxInterstitial.loadAd(SourceFile:2)
    at com.tappx.unity.interstitialTappx$1.run(interstitialTappx.java:39)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988819/android-p-api-28-what-does-the-strictmode-policy-violation-smartselectionev

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are referring to the usage of hidden, system level APIs in your App, most likely included in third party code and often required for certain functionality. For Android P(28), there is a [light-greylist](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/pie-release/config/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt) of hidden APIs that are OK to use currently, but may be deprecated in a later version. There is also a dark-greylist and a blacklist. Above your Stack Trace you should have a line that says `API LAndroid/...` You should be able to search that string without the "API " and hopefully will find it in the light-greylist linked above. If so, you should be fine for now. If not, it is possible the API is going to be deprecated/removed in Android Q and you may need to fix it before being able to upgrade to support SDK 29. Please note that if there are legitimate use cases for a greylisted API Google should create a new API to address those needs. More information about non-SDK interfaces can be found [in this Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988819/android-p-api-28-what-does-the-strictmode-policy-violation-smartselectionev).

Additional information about the different levels of greylist and distribution best practices are also provided in this [Android guide about Non-SDK Restrictions](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces). Please note that you may have to copy this link and paste it into your browser.

Comment: Cool. Is there a lint check in AS to show which lines of code are creating this issue?

Comment: @BondPBond **Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)** & **Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)** there other non-sdk in my project. Mostly AudioManager non-sdk come while use Admob Ads