# Ljava/nio/Byffer;-;address:J - the gray list

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Help with the following flaw that appears in google play. What can be? What code do you need as such? then I leave my android manifest. Which is where I think the problem might be.

Google can not guarantee that the following APIs will work in the current versions of Android because they are in the gray list. It is possible that some are already restricted for your destination SDK.

Ljava/nio/Byffer;-;address:J -

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
at akj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):78)
at akj.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):76)
at akj.<clinit>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):116)
at akj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):26)
at ajd.<clinit>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):2502)
at ajd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):20)
at aio.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):26)
at ajl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):3)
at ajl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):8)
at ahr.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):88)
at ww.h_(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):23)
at tl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):18)
at td.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):12)
at tg.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):56)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at xs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):5)
at xs.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@15090081@15.0.90 (100400-231259764):4)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android P (API 28) - What does the StrictMode policy violation "SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988819/android-p-api-28-what-does-the-strictmode-policy-violation-smartselectionev)